# sign in required environment sandbox issue

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, ios11

Everytime I build an adhoc build and runs it on ios 11 it keeps popping up the message saying "Sign-In Required - Enter the password for ***** [Environment:Sandbox]". Thus, this keep activating like a loop and not going away. tried siging out from iCloud also but didn't work.My inAppPurchase code as bellow.

```
class InAppPurchase: NSObject,SKProductsRequestDelegate, 

SKPaymentTransactionObserver {


    ///Singleton
    private static var inappPurChase:InAppPurchase?;

    public static var shared:InAppPurchase {
        if inappPurChase == nil{
            inappPurChase = InAppPurchase()
        }
        return inappPurChase!
    }
    override private init() {
        //Singleton complete
    }
    ////////////

    var productsList = [SKProduct]()
    var productToPurchase = SKProduct()
    var productID = ""
    let PURCHASE_ID_PREFIX = ""//"com.purelightbeta."
    var onInAppPurchaseSuccess: (()->Void )? = nil
    var onInAppPurchaseError: (()->Void )? = nil
    var onNoProductsIDs: (()->Void )? = nil
    var appEnvironment: ((String,Bool)->Void )? = nil
    var onReceiptVarificationError: (()->Void )? = nil
    var onRestorePurchaseError: ((String)->Void )? = nil
    var onRestoreProductsIDs: ((NSMutableArray)->Void )? = nil


    public func initPayment (productID: String) {
        self.productID = PURCHASE_ID_PREFIX + productID
        print("Initializing Purchase Product ID: \(self.productID)")
        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
            let productID: NSSet = NSSet(objects: self.productID)
            let request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()
        }else {
            print("In App Purchases not enabled")
        }
    }

    func buyProduct() {
        let payment = SKPayment(product: productToPurchase)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment as SKPayment)
    }


    public func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        let myProducts = response.products
        print(myProducts)
        productsList = []
        if myProducts.count == 0 {
            print("No products")
            if(onNoProductsIDs != nil){
            onNoProductsIDs!()
            }
        }
        for product in myProducts {
            print("Prod Details :\(product.productIdentifier) \(product.price) \(product.localizedDescription)")
            productsList.append(product)
        }


        for product in productsList {
            let productID = product.productIdentifier
            if productID == self.productID {
                productToPurchase = product
                buyProduct()
            }
        }

    }

    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
        let productIDs: NSMutableArray = []
        for trasacton in queue.transactions {
            if trasacton.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionState.restored
            {
                let t: SKPaymentTransaction = trasacton as SKPaymentTransaction
                let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String
                print("prodID:",prodID)

                //let appStoreId = prodID.components(separatedBy: "com.purelightbeta.")

                productIDs.add(prodID)
                SKPaymentQueue .default().finishTransaction(trasacton)

            }

        }
        if onRestoreProductsIDs != nil {
            print(productIDs)
            onRestoreProductsIDs! (productIDs)
        }

    }

    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction: AnyObject in transactions {
            let trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
            print(trans.error ?? "No in app error")
            switch trans.transactionState {
            case .purchased:
                print("buy ok, AIP unlocked for item :", productToPurchase.productIdentifier)
                let productID =  productToPurchase.productIdentifier

                switch productID {
                case self.productID:
                    print("Item found")
                   //  startValidatingReceipt()
                default:
                    print("Item not found")
                }
                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                if self.onInAppPurchaseSuccess != nil {
                   self.onInAppPurchaseSuccess! ()
                    self.startValidatingReceipt()
                }
            case .failed:
                print("buy error")
                if self.onInAppPurchaseError != nil {
                    self.onInAppPurchaseError! ()

                }
                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break

            case .restored:
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
               // break

            default:
                print("default")
                break
            }

        }
    }
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError error: Error) {
         print("ERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        if onRestorePurchaseError != nil {
           onRestorePurchaseError! (error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    func restorePurchase() {
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()

    }



    func startValidatingReceipt() {
        if let isExists = try? self.getReceiptURL()?.checkResourceIsReachable(), isExists == true {
            do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: self.getReceiptURL()!)
               // self.startValidatingData(data: data)
                self.sendReceiptToLocalServer(data: data)
            }catch {
                let appReceiptRefreshRequest = SKReceiptRefreshRequest(receiptProperties: nil)
                appReceiptRefreshRequest.delegate = self
                appReceiptRefreshRequest.start()
            }
        }else {
        print("No receipt for this purchase")
        }
    }
    func getReceiptURL() -> URL? {
        return Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL
    }


    enum receiptValidationURLs:String {
        case sandbox = "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"
        case production = "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"

        static var url:URL{
            if isDebug {
            return URL.init(string: self.sandbox.rawValue)!
            }else{
            return URL.init(string: self.production.rawValue)!
            }
        }
    }
    func sendReceiptToLocalServer(data:Data) {
        let base64encodedReceipt = data.base64EncodedString()

        if self.appEnvironment != nil {
            self.appEnvironment! (base64encodedReceipt,isDebug)
        }
    }
    func startValidatingData(data:Data){


        let base64encodedReceipt = data.base64EncodedString()
        print(base64encodedReceipt)
        let requestDictionary = ["receipt-data":base64encodedReceipt]
        guard JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(requestDictionary) else {  print("requestDictionary is not valid JSON");  return }
        do {
            let requestData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: requestDictionary)
       //     let validationURLString = "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"  // this works but as noted above it's best to use your own trusted server
            NSLog("The Environment is: %@", receiptValidationURLs.url.absoluteString)
            guard let validationURL = URL(string: receiptValidationURLs.url.absoluteString) else { print("the validation url could not be created, unlikely error"); return }
            let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
            var request = URLRequest(url: validationURL)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.cachePolicy = URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData
            let task = session.uploadTask(with: request, from: requestData) { (data, response, error) in
                if let data = data , error == nil {
                    do {
                       let appReceiptJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
                         print((appReceiptJSON as AnyObject).count)
                         print("success. here is the json representation of the app receipt: \(appReceiptJSON)")
                         NSLog("Receipt is: %@", appReceiptJSON as! NSDictionary)
                         if let environment = (appReceiptJSON as? NSDictionary)?["environment"]{

                         if self.appEnvironment != nil {
                            self.appEnvironment! (environment as? String ?? "No value",isDebug)
                         }
                        }
                    } catch let error as NSError {
                        print("json serialization failed with error: \(error)")
                    }
                } else {
                    print("the upload task returned an error: \(error)")
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("json serialization failed with error: \(error)")
        }
    }

//    func requestDidFinish(_ request: SKRequest) {
//        // a fresh receipt should now be present at the url
//        do {
//
//            
//
//        } catch {
//            // still no receipt, possible but unlikely to occur since this is the "success" delegate method
//        }
//    }

    func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("app receipt refresh request did fail with error: \(error)")
        // for some clues see here: https://samritchie.net/2015/01/29/the-operation-couldnt-be-completed-sserrordomain-error-100/
        if self.onReceiptVarificationError != nil {
            self.onReceiptVarificationError! ()
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: could you please post your IAP code here... I think you are doing something wrong with your observer handling

Comment: Code been updated and its been posted

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer but would be a workaround. Best is to create a new sandbox user, sign out the old one and put the new.